# Avoid current_user hitting db every time? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, cookies

I am following [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec-authorization). The codes are given,

in sessions helper:

```
  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token= User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token]=remember_token #save the unencrypted token to browser cookies
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user= user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user= user
  end

  def current_user
    encrypted_token=User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||=User.find_by(remember_token:encrypted_token)
  end

  def sign_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

in navigator view:

```
<% if sign_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Profile",current_user %></li>
<% end %>
```

My questions are:

1. Is it hitting the database every time when a visitor refreshes the navigator?
2. Can I reduce db hits by using @current_user in views and changing the `sign_in?` function to:

> ```
> def sign_in?
>   if @current_user.nil?
>     !current_user.nil?
>   else
>     false
>   end
> end
> ```

3.What are the best practices to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No "solution".

HTTP server is stateless. Every request is new. The instance variable only lives in each request, which means in next request it won't exist.

The only way to remember "state" of this user is to save some data to db and authenticate him every time he requests.

No worries about the db, they are designed to be run :)

Comment: I am not sure how stateless HTTP server affect my method. Or is it a security issue instead? Can you please give me more details about how my method will fail? I have deployed my method on heroku https://sample-app-ivan.herokuapp.com

Comment: Because HTTP server is stateless, user need to be authenticated at every request. So in every request there is a db hit, to find this user from database. I don't know why and how your method failed, as you just asked why db got hit in question.

Comment: A better approach would be using instance variable to cache the db search in method in Controller, like `def current_user; @current_user || User.find(...); end;` The reason is you'll need current_user for lots of time. Next time, within same request, you don't need to hit db again to find it. However, using it as instance variable in view is not encouraged.

Comment: Got it. I believe my change on "sign_in?" is unnecessary. The server will forget @current_user in the next request anyway. My heroku works fine, but it actually didn't save db hits. Db still have to be hit at least once each time loading the page. So that using "@current_user" is also unnecessary. Messing up var "@current_user" in views will only confuse the other developers.

Answer (score 3):

I think your solution is fine and does not need fixing.

I do have two suggestions/alternatives for you which you might want to explore if you are not happy with the current situation (***I would however not recommend these over your solution, I'm just going to illustrate the alternatives***):

1. **Use sessions instead of a DB**. HTTP is stateless. However, sessions were invented to make http
   statefull. You could use session, and store a reference to the
   currentuser there. You could then check for the presence of the user_id in the session, instead of hitting the db every time. This of course degrades your security. It would depend on the nature of your application whether this should be acceptable to you.
2. **Only check credentials on accesslevel change**.  This is a somewhat more pragmatisch/loose approach to user authorization. ***It is up to you if you find this degradation in security acceptable in your case***.
   It works as follows: for example we have a simple website with pages. The lowest accesslevel is read-level, if a user decides to edit a page, he goes to write-level. In this approach, the change of accesslevel would be the moment you do a full authentication check again. So, not everytime, only if you change accesslevels re-authenticate and re-authorize a user. Maybe you also want to determine randomly if you are going to re-authenticate/re-authorize or not, this avoids predictability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [second-level-cache](https://github.com/csdn-dev/second_level_cache) to save database requests if record loading is simple. However since you look up user using some kind of key, this won't work.

However loading user from database every time should be okay. It is a common practice in Rails projects.